# Sync opened tabs across computers?

Tags: browser, sync, tabs, bookmarks

Say I was doing research on Black Friday shopping and I opened 30 tabs in 5 windows at office. I want to continue the research at home. I could use remote desktop, but it would be much better if I can simply click a button and have all the tabs loaded at home.

To achieve that, I was going to write a plugin to automatically save all opened tabs on a server. But I'm afraid I'm re-inventing the wheel. Do you know any existing software that can do just this?

(Answers for any major browser is OK)

Comment: I found two useful Google Chrome extensions, TabCloud: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/npecfdijgoblfcgagoijgmgejmcpnhof and FreshStart: https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/nmidkjogcjnnlfimjcedenagjfacpobb

Answer (score 3):

Firefox can do so using [Firefox Sync](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/10868/) (previously known as Mozilla Weave)

---

[Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) can [do so](http://blog.xmarks.com/?p=1643) across any device with a browser.

---

[This workaround](http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=19649) allows you to sync tabs in Opera.

Comment: I thought Xmarks can only sync bookmarks. Thanks for the link! I wish  Xmarks will continue to provide some free service after being acquired =)

Comment: +1 - Xmarks rocks.  @netvope: I think they will continue to provide a free service, alongside a premium service (details not clear yet) - http://blog.xmarks.com/?p=2007

Comment: Firefox doesn't really sync the tabs, as in the 30 tabs in 5 windows appear on your other computers, it just makes a list of tabs available on your other computers. I wish I could actually get it to load the tabs over on the other computers too.

Answer (score 1):

Opera can do so using [Sync Open Tabs](http://druss.pp.ua/sync-open-tabs/) [extension](https://addons.opera.com/ru/extensions/details/sync-open-tabs/).

Answer (score 0):

Google Chrome has this functionality built in.  Check out this [article](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en-GB&answer=2591582) on how to open tabs from Chrome on other devices.  It allows you to see the tabs opened on other devices, open them one or all of them.